# Use a column alias from a cross join in the returning part of a cte

Tags: postgresql

I need to use an inserted column alias from a cross join in the returning part of the cte. Please see following example with comment:

```
WITH cte (
  INSERT INTO something (one, two)
  SELECT i->>'a', d.key AS t, o.somefield
  FROM jsonb_array_elements('[{"a": 1, "b": 2},{"a":3, "b": 4}]') AS i
  CROSS JOIN jsonb_each('{"c": 1, "d": 2}') AS d(key, value)
  JOIN someothercte o ON o.value = d.value
  RETURNING id, t; -- d.key or t is not avilable here
)
```

Comment: Your `SELECT` clause has three columns but your `INSERT` statement has only two? Did you mean to insert `i->>'a'` as `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RETURNING` clause is evaluated against the `INSERT` target table, i.e. `something`. You'll need to use `one` and `two` as column names, `two` referring to the value that your `SELECT` clause selected with `d.key AS t`:

```
WITH cte (
  INSERT INTO something (id, one, two)
  SELECT i->>'a', d.key AS t, o.somefield
    FROM jsonb_array_elements('[{"a": 1, "b": 2},{"a":3, "b": 4}]') AS i
    CROSS JOIN jsonb_each('{"c": 1, "d": 2}') AS d(key, value)
    JOIN someothercte o ON o.value = d.value
  RETURNING id, two
)
```